# How to fetch recordNumber string

Tags: javascript

I have a string as below and i wanted to extract the `recordNumber` value i.e `RSLC-2022-00000034`

```
{"Response":{"status":"200","result":{"result":{"Success":true,"Message":"","ErrorCode":null},"data":{"recordId":"22CAP-00000-000YG","recordNumber":"RSLC-2022-00000034","recordBalance":"0.0","recordFees":null}}}}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(someStringYouHave).Response.result.data.recordNumber`

Comment: It's throwing error as "error in catch SyntaxError: Unexpected token: o"

Comment: If that is the error you got then that is not the string you provided in the question. The string in the question is valid JSON and calling `JSON.parse` on it would not give that error.

Comment: so, you don't have a String at all, you have an object ... so it's `someObjectYouHave.Response.result.data.recordNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
  "Response": {
    "status": "200",
    "result": {
      "result": {
        "Success": true,
        "Message": "",
        "ErrorCode": null
      },
      "data": {
        "recordId": "22CAP-00000-000YG",
        "recordNumber": "RSLC-2022-00000034",
        "recordBalance": "0.0",
        "recordFees": null
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(data.Response.result.data.recordNumber)
```